# gitignore error while creating loopbackjs app

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I downloaded `loopbackjs` on my windows using the npm command. But while creating an app there is an error showing constantly.

```
node:events:368


throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Rohit Pandey\rohit-pandey\_.gitignore'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1390:3)
    at exports.readdir (C:\Users\Rohit Pandey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@loopback\cli\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib\sync\fs.js:18:20)
    at Object.safeCall [as safe] (C:\Users\Rohit Pandey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@loopback\cli\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib\call.js:24:8)
    at DirectoryReader.readNextDirectory (C:\Users\Rohit Pandey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@loopback\cli\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib\directory-reader.js:78:10)
    at Readable.DirectoryReader.stream._read (C:\Users\Rohit Pandey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@loopback\cli\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib\directory-reader.js:57:18)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:496:27)
    at readdirSync (C:\Users\Rohit Pandey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@loopback\cli\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib\sync\index.js:27:21)
    at Function.readdirSyncStat (C:\Users\Rohit Pandey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@loopback\cli\node_modules\@mrmlnc\readdir-enhanced\lib\index.js:34:10)
    at ReaderSync.dynamicApi (C:\Users\Rohit Pandey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@loopback\cli\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\fast-glob\out\providers\reader-sync.js:64:24)
    at ReaderSync.api (C:\Users\Rohit Pandey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@loopback\cli\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\fast-glob\out\providers\reader-sync.js:56:25)
Emitted 'error' event on Readable instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Rohit Pandey\\rohit-pandey\\_.gitignore'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue that we are actively tracking: [gitignore error while creating loopbackjs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70156515/gitignore-error-while-creating-loopbackjs-app)

A workaround is to downgrade to an LTS release of Node.js (At this time of writing, v14 and v16).

As a best practice, we recommend sticking to LTS releases of Node.js to ensure stability as there have been breaking changes that occurred within Current releases, and to provide the maintainers time to investigate.

Comment: I recommend adding that disclaimer to the Getting Started documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with node version.
I had downloaded most recent Node 17 which had backward compatibility issue.SO i downloaded LTS version of Nodejs.
It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading node from version `v17.2.0` to `v16.13.1` helped me fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the .gitignore file inside the `C:\Users\Rohit Pandey\rohit-pandey\` does not exist. Create it and the problem should be gone.

Comment: loopbackjs itself creates directory and file from scratch. I tried to do what you said before posting the question. it does not work that way. But thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: While it looks prima-facie that this is the issue, the parent folder itself is created by Loopback CLI